# Merging two projects in 2 different SVN repo to one of the repo

Tags: ios, xcode, git, svn, version-control

In one of my iPhone projects named Proj A, I worked on an SVN repo, say Repo A. And I had to do some R&D on the same project and so I took the source code and put it in a separate SVN repo Repo B. I had been working in Repo A and Repo B independently for around 10 months now. I have added new files in repo A and modified the existing files in repo B. Now I need to merge the source code in Repo A and Repo B to repo A. Is it possible to do this in SVN and if possible how shall I do this?

Comment: Do you want to keep the history of both branches? An easy way is to copy the files of one branch over the files of the other, but you will lose the history of one branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it directly but below is the way that can do something in automated way.

1. Take checkout from Repo B.
2. Delete all SVN info from it. (Simple command line operation).
3. Take checkout from Repo A.
4. Overwrite all the code from Repo B to Repo A.
5. Sync it with server and it will show all the differences.
6. Merge them and commit.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

> I took the source code and put it in a separate SVN repo Repo B

How you done it is important:

If you used dump|load cycle and preserved UUID of RepoA in RepoB (check it with `svn info` in WCs of repos) you can

- relocate Working Copy of any repo to URL of another repo (another node, than changed code in repository-recipient, `REPO/<some branch>` will be good choice)
- merge two nodes in united repository